# foursquare api v2 not getting reply for herenow

Tags: foursquare

using v2 api

url

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/4d5db152e0ffa1cdb12a1e54/herenow?oauth_token=FSQ_USER_TOKEN&v=20111205&limit=100
```

Consistent replies since yesterday

```
{"meta":{"code":200},"notifications":[{"type":"notificationTray","item":{"unreadCount":0}}],"response":{"hereNow":{"count":0,"items":[]}}}
```

But I know that there are 2 checkins, 1 is mine.  When I go to Foursquare.com I see the checkins for the venues.  This started yesterday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you're calling the right endpoint? Herenow returns information about people currently checked in. For total number of check-ins, you'll want to call [venues/4d5db152e0ffa1cdb12a1e54](https://foursquare.com/v/jt-buffalo-wings/4d5db152e0ffa1cdb12a1e54) and look at the "stats" stanza

Comment: People currently at that location is what i am interested in.  I checked in to the location, then tried the query.  It returned nothing, but when I went to https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/ and did the Recent Checkins, it showed it.  BTW - tried the hereNow from here too, and showed nil also.

Comment: recent check-ins will always return the user's most recent check-in (+ the most recent check-in of their friends). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771514/when-checking-in-via-foursquare-api-i-do-not-show-up-in-here-now/8791164#8791164 for a potential reason your check-ins may not be appearing in herenow

Comment: As per other question linked above.  Added lat and lng to checkin and now working.  Weird thing is that this started after Jan 4th.