# Foursquare api doesn't return correct checkins information

Tags: foursquare

I was tested foursquare api to use it in future projects and faced a strange problem.

I will explain it in example. 
You check in via Swarm app to the place 1 and call **venue here now** endpoint

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/559bac8f498effd9368131f6/herenow?v=20160606&oauth_token=<token>
```

you receive correct data, your user is displayed in items array field

```
"response":{"hereNow":{"count":2,"items":[{"id":"583ede91a36ecd3aeee51647","createdAt":1480515217,"type":"checkin","timeZoneOffset":120,"user":{"id":"355625527","firstName":"Dima","gender":"male","relationship":"self","photo":{"prefix":"https:\/\/irs0.4sqi.net\/img\/user\/","suffix":"\/blank_boy.png","default":true}},"likes":{"count":0,"groups":[]},"like":false},{"id":"583ede0a02b60e59094ddbc5","createdAt":1480515082,"type":"checkin","timeZoneOffset":120,"user":{"id":"43963436","firstName":"Ayhan","lastName":"B","gender":"male","photo":{"prefix":"https:\/\/irs0.4sqi.net\/img\/user\/","suffix":"\/43963436-UWAYC333GLM2YQ4H.jpg"}}}]}}
```

Then you check in to place 2 and call same endpoint. The check in data is correct, your user is in items array.
But when you check in back to place 1, your user are not included in items array

```
"response":{"hereNow":{"count":1,"items":[{"id":"583ede0a02b60e59094ddbc5","createdAt":1480515082,"type":"checkin","timeZoneOffset":120,"user":{"id":"43963436","firstName":"Ayhan","lastName":"B","gender":"male","photo":{"prefix":"https:\/\/irs0.4sqi.net\/img\/user\/","suffix":"\/43963436-UWAYC333GLM2YQ4H.jpg"}}}]}}
```

Instead foursquare thoughts that you are still checked in to place 2.

Also when you **check in recent** endpoint it will return that your recent check in is to place 1

```
"response":{"recent":[{"id":"583ee16ed8b0ed757138ec10","createdAt":1480515950,"type":"checkin","timeZoneOffset":120,"user":{"id":"355625527","firstName":"Dima","gender":"male","relationship":"self","photo":{"prefix":"https:\/\/irs0.4sqi.net\/img\/user\/","suffix":"\/blank_boy.png","default":true}},"venue":{"id":"559bac8f498effd9368131f6","name":"Львiвськi  пляцки","contact":{"phone":"0936567878","formattedPhone":"093 656 7878","facebook":"288574604603052","facebookUsername":"lvivskipljacky","facebookName":"Львівські пляцки"},"location":{"address":"вул. Богдана Хмельницького, 10","lat":50.44546701910413,"lng":30.51702892776601,"labeledLatLngs":[{"label":"display","lat":50.44546701910413,"lng":30.51702892776601}],"postalCode":"01001","cc":"UA","city":"Kyiv","state":"Kyiv City","country":"Ukraine","formattedAddress":["вул. Богдана Хмельницького, 10","Kyiv, 01001"]},"categories":[{"id":"4bf58dd8d48988d16a941735","name":"Bakery","pluralName":"Bakeries","shortName":"Bakery","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss3.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/food\/bakery_","suffix":".png"},"primary":true}],"verified":false,"stats":{"checkinsCount":2782,"usersCount":1890,"tipCount":75},"url":"http:\/\/www.fest.lviv.ua\/uk\/restaurants\/lvivskipljacky\/","allowMenuUrlEdit":true,"beenHere":{"unconfirmedCount":0,"marked":false,"lastCheckinExpiredAt":0},"specials":{"count":0}},"source":{"name":"Swarm for Android","url":"https:\/\/www.swarmapp.com"},"photos":{"count":0,"items":[]},"posts":{"count":0,"textCount":0},"likes":{"count":0,"groups":[]},"like":false,"comments":{"count":0},"isMayor":false}]}
```

Did anyone also face this problem too? Or does foursquare api have some limitation for check-ins? I searched though web about it, but cannot find any useful information

Comment: Don't know how I can miss it, but found this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771514/when-checking-in-via-foursquare-api-i-do-not-show-up-in-here-now?rq=1
It describes check-in logic, and very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A user will show in the venue "Here Now" for 3 hours after they checkin OR until they checkin at another venue. In your example, a user will not appear in Place 1s "here now" if their checkin pattern is Place 1 -> Place 2 -> Place 1. I'm not sure if this is a bug or done intentionally as a quality control.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Yes, it makes sense, but it will be very good if it will be documented in docs.